# What is the use case of docker Ubuntu images

Tags: docker

I'm new to this containers. I have seen docker doing really awesome job in virtualization. what is the point of using OS images like Ubuntu, centos etc. For an example if I need  to run a mysql server. I can pull it up and just simply run it. I don't think so i need a help of another os image. Can anyone clarify this ? Thanks.

Comment: The MySQL image is based on Debian: https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/5.7/Dockerfile. You need an OS somewhere. You may not need to use those images *directly*, usually you'll use a prepackaged service or a language-based image, but they're still used.

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe thanks, btw for an example let's get jenkins docker file https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/Dockerfile. I couldn't see any base OS image on that. Can you explain please ?

Comment: Well did you look at what the openjdk image uses? Follow the chain up.

Comment: So eventually it uses somehow a base image. Am I correct ?

Comment: Answer the question. Did you follow it? What did you find?

Comment: Yep, I found it. Base on Debian OS. Thanks for guidance

Comment: No problem! "Stretch" is an early giveaway, that's the code name of Debian 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These Linux-distribution images are useful as a base for further images.  It’s common enough to build an Ubuntu-based image for some specific application, for example:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install ...
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
CMD ["./myapp"]
```

To the extent that you might need, say, a PostgreSQL client library, getting it via a standard distribution package manager is much more convenient than building it from source.

You’re right that there’s basically no point in directly running these images.

(You’re also right that you don’t *need* a distribution: if you have a statically-linked binary, you can build an image `FROM scratch` that contains *only* the application itself and not common niceties like the system C library or a shell.  I’ve mostly only seen this for Go applications; it can be very hard to use and debug otherwise if you’re not confident in Docker.)